# Laravel 4: Get complete query log

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, query-builder

I was trying to do debugging to my query builder. So I am using `getQueryLog()` to get the last executed query. But the problem is the displayed query is incomplete. It shows something like this:

```
 update `slideshow` set `position` = ? where `position` = ?
```

I can't see the value in "?". How can I have it to display the complete query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to see last queries you can use these lines some where in your code, like if you want to see all queries that executed at the time of user list page than in your UserController.php, you can add these lines at the end(before return/response) of index() method:

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
print_r($queries);
```

This is not a great idea but these line will output all queries those got executed in page load. It outputs with query and params of query.